# Contained sticky sidebar

Tags: jquery, fixed, sidebar, sticky

I need a sidebar that stays with a **fixed position** when the user scrools the page. I came across a lot of solutions and all very clunky, to complex, or too long. I need it simple and efficient. I tried and made this:

```
var length = $( '#container' ).height() - $( '#stick' ).offset().top - parseFloat($( '#stick' ).css( 'marginTop' ).replace(/auto/, 0));

$(window).scroll(function () {

    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scroll < $( '#container' ).offset().top) {
      $( '#stick' ).removeAttr("style");
    }
    else if (scroll > length) {
      $( '#stick' ).css('position', 'absolute');
    }
    else {
      $( '#stick' ).css({"position":"fixed", "top":"0", "right":"0"});
    }
});
```

I made this with the help of [Remy Sharp screencast](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/) and [waypointarts blog post](http://www.waypointarts.com/blog/2013/06/29/fixing-a-side-bar-while-scrolling-until-bottom)

When the #container gets at the end of viewport the #stick stops scrolling (the "fixed" position is removed), the problem is that it disapears and does not stay with absolute position in that location, and this behaviour distracts the user.

**How can I make the #stick sidebar be absolutely positioned in the bottom of #container instead of disappearing?** Also do you think my code could be perfected someway?

I'm amateur and start using jquery one month now so you will find a lot of mistakes here...

Thank you.

Comment: When enough browsers support it, it will be possible to use [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning)

Comment: wow that is so awesome. I didn't know this position would be available. Thanks for pointing it. Not a solid option right now: http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it. I don't know why it was desapearing, however I decided to not inject css properties directly into the html, and use a more apropriate approach for css, applying the css in the actual css file because html it's supposed to have html language.

So with this thought I added css classes with the jquery actions and in the css I added the styles I wanted for those classes, and everything is working perfectly. Maybe it was some overlapping css rule that did some error before... Anyway now it has better approach and it's better formatted.

So, the html:

```
<body>
  <header>The header</header>
  <main id="container">
    <article id="content">Main content</article>
    <section id="sticky">Sticking content</section>
  </main>
  <footer>The footer</footer>
<body>
```

The jquery:

```
var $container = $( '#container' );
var $sticky    = $( '#sticky' );
var length     = $container.height() + $container.offset().top - $sticky.height();

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y < $container.offset().top) { $sticky.removeClass('sticky-fixed sticky-bottom'); }
    else if (y > length) { $sticky.attr('class','sticky sticky-bottom'); }
    else { $sticky.attr('class','sticky sticky-fixed'); }
});
```

The css:

```
#sticky {
    width: 260px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 128px;
    }

#sticky-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 128px;
    }

#sticky-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: auto;
    }
```

**What this does:**

If the page is at the top the #sticky will have "position absolute", when the user starts scrolling the page it will have "position fixed" (always visible in the side of the content) and when the viewpoint gets to the bottom of the #container, which have the main content, the sticky will stop there.

The main advantage of this approach is that the "section sticky" will not overlap the "footer" or any other html element bellow it. **It will stop at the end of the #container**, and since will have a "fixed" position will not distract the user following the viewpoint whenever the user scrolls the page.

This is the best I could do and seems much more easier and light than other full scripts I found around. If it has any error or if it can be further updated please improve it and let us know.

Since jquery part is done, it should be easy to adapt for other people, just change the css file properties to your taste.